# Understanding master Page scope

Tags: master-page

I have a site (not site collection) for which I would like to add a customized Site Master Page. When I open the site in SharePoint Designer, I see

```
default.master
minimal.master
v4.master
```

The master page that I would like to customize is `nightandday.master`. Do I have to go back to the containing site collection do do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the master page available in top level site, then you have to go and modify that in the top level site.

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT modify that master page directly.  That is a Microsoft page and is subject to change in Service Packs and updates and could subsequently be replaced when those are applied.  Make a copy of it and modify the copy then select the copy as the master page for your sub site.